# How is the fraction of individuals with negative income handled in calculating the Gini coefficient in grouped data?

Tags: econometrics, macroeconomics, gini

Much of the literature on theorizing and estimating the [Gini coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/gini/info) [$G$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/gini/info) is predicated upon the lower bound of the income distribution being $\$0$ (or whatever your unit of currency is); that is, no one has a negative income. However, here in the real world negative incomes exist. For example, in 2017, the IRS recorded over 2 million returns with negative adjusted gross incomes averaging at about $(\$11,090)$ per capita. These returns account for a bit under 1.5% of all returns.

**Are negative incomes simply ignored in Gini coefficient calculations? Or perhaps assumed to have an average income of $\boldsymbol{\$0}$?**

**Are they integrated into the calculation somehow? If so, how do they affect the lower income bracket calculations for grouped data?**